# Сокращение PHP (Рефакторинг)

Tags: php, phalcon

Решил сократить некоторые части кода PHP, раньше с подобным особо не сталкивался.

Код после сокращения идеально работает но вопрос в том стоит ли так делать, какие могут быть последствия - Вот код контролера регистрации:

```
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->users    = new Users();
        $this->request  = $this->request->getJsonRawBody(true);
    }

    public function RegistrationAction()
    {
        return $this->users->assign(
            $this->request,
            [
                'email',
                'password',
                'first_name',
                'last_name'
            ]
        )->save() ? true : $this->ModelError($this->users);
    }
}
```

Точка входа в приложения:

```
<?php
define('APP', '../App/');
define('CONF', require_once APP . 'Config.php');

try {
    $services = new Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault();

    (new Phalcon\Autoload\Loader())
        ->setDirectories([
            APP . 'Controllers/',
            APP . 'Models/'
        ])
        ->setFiles(
            glob(APP . 'Services/*.php')
        )
        ->register();

    (new Phalcon\Mvc\Application($services))
        ->handle($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
        ->send();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    (new BaseController())
        ->Exception($e)
        ->send();
}
```

Comment: " стоит ли так делать"  --- так - это как?

Comment: Я о том что возможно есть более правильная реализация.

Comment: Правильная реализация чего?

Comment: К примеру класс RegistrationAction вернее содержимой код - вызов функций можно разместить в переменной и после её вернуть а не сразу объявлять return.

Comment: как хочется. зависит от читабельности и от того, какой конвеншн принят в организации.